# React Functional component unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to rewrite this component https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/examples/react_advanced_demo/src/JSONEditorReact.js
to a functional component.
I made this:

```js
const Editor = ({json, mode, onChange}) => {
  const elRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      onChangeText: onChange,
      onChangeJson: onChange,
    };

    const jsonEditor = new JSONEditor(elRef.current, options);
    if (jsonEditor) {
      if (json) {
        jsonEditor.set(json);
      }

      if (mode) {
        jsonEditor.setMode(mode);
      }
    }

    return () => {
      if (jsonEditor) {
        jsonEditor.destroy();
      }
    }
  },[json,mode]);
  
  return (
    <div
      className={styles.jsoneditor_react_container}
      ref={elRef}
    />
  )
}

export default Editor;
```

My question is next: Is it correct to unmount the component `jsonEditor.destroy();` inside that useEffect with [json, mode] dependancies or i should create another useEffect with empty dependancy array to get the same behaviour as in class component?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is fine provided that destroying and rebuilding the `JSONEditor` doesn't take discernible time or cause a visual twitch that's apparent to the user. The editor *will* be cleaned up when the component is unmounted.

But, since it seems to allow you to *change* mode and JSON on an existing instance (based on [the API](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md)), I think I'd do that rather than completely destroying it and rebuilding it when those change:

```
const Editor = ({json, mode, onChange}) => {
  const elRef = useRef(null);
  const edRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // On mount
    const options = {
      onChangeText: onChange,
      onChangeJson: onChange,
    };

    const jsonEditor = edRef.current = new JSONEditor(elRef.current, options);
    if (json) {                 //
      jsonEditor.set(json);     // I don't think you actually need these here,
    }                           // I *think* `useEffect` callbacks are run in
    if (mode) {                 // order so the below will do it. But...
      jsonEditor.setMode(mode); //
    }                           //

    return () => {
      // No `if`, you *know* it exists
      jsonEditor.destroy();
      edRef.current = null;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const jsonEditor = edRef.current;
    if (!jsonEditor) { // I don't think this can happen
      return;
    }
    if (json) {
      jsonEditor.set(json);
    }
    if (mode) {
      jsonEditor.setMode(mode);
    }
  }, [json, mode]);
  
  return (
    <div
      className={styles.jsoneditor_react_container}
      ref={elRef}
    />
  );
};

export default Editor;
```

But that's more complicated, so if what you're doing works well and provides the user experience you want, you might want to leave it alone.